# How to handle binary data returned from barcode scanner?

Tags: java, javascript, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have a 2d barcode scanner (Honeywell Xenon 1900).

Scanning 1D barcodes is easy, as the scanner emulates keyboard events and sends plain text.

But when I scan [PDF417 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF417) 2D barcodes, the scanner sends binary data. How can I capture and decode this data? Some of symbols are non-printable, so scanning into a form on a web page wouldn't work.

Comment: Maybe post a sample response?

Comment: you have your answer in your post, just look at the link more closely (ISO in wiki)

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article, the barcode can contain actual binary data, so it would make sense that this is the output, right? What if you generate your own 2D barcode with only ASCII data; do you get text back from the scanner?

Comment: How can the scanner emulate keyboard when it's sending binary data? Makes no sense to me. The answer lies within "the scanner sends..." where and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution for this question is using COM-port.

I configure scanner, so it sends data not as keyboard events, but in virtual COM-port.
Then I have Java-applet, that listens this port (using RXTX). Then COM-port is not empty, I can get data and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged this java as well as javascript. However you truly haven't given us any details of your application. Nonetheless, dealing with the transporting of binary data in javascript, can be done using the base64 protocol. Use two methods `btoa()` and `atob()`.

```
function toBase64 () {
            return window.btoa(data);
        }
function fromBase64 (strBase64){
            data = window.atob(strBase64);
        }
```

I think the concept for you though, (and I'm just guessing since you haven't explained what you are doing in any detail), would be to `base64` **ENCODE** the data before transporting it to the javascript/html/web application. You'll be doing this using java I suppose. Once you send the base64 encoded data to your web application, you can deal with it quite easily.

Comment: This is elegant and simple-to-implement solution. But I can't find configuration option for my scanner to use BASE64 format.